# graphical emacs on windows - scrolling slow

Tags: microsoft-windows, scrolling

I am using emacs 25.1, the "official" minGW build, on Windows 7.  Opening a very simple text file, even with emacs -Q, leads to slow scrolling.  Hit PgUp/Down and it takes time.  This happens when I run emacs as a windows program.  If I go into a command window, and run emacs -nw (either minGW or cygwin), scrolling is fine and fast.

So, what is wrong?  This is super duper annoying.  Modern computers are powerful enough to scroll a few pages of text instantly...

Comment: Does setting `fast-but-imprecise-scrolling` to `t` help any?  Does the problem happen in `fundamental-mode`, or are you in `text-mode` with `font-lock-mode` globally enabled?  When `fast-but-imprecise-scrolling` is set to `t`, the internal function `window_scroll` binds `fontification_functions` to `nil`.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but changing it from nil to t doesn't help, in either text or fundamental modes.  The same slowness also can happen if I move the cursor to the next screen just with up/down arrows.  M-x describe-modes indicates a lot of minor modes are active.  Can I turn them all off?  I must be doing something wrong...

Comment: I see you found the issue -- good job.  When debugging, yes, turning off minor-modes to help narrow down the problem is sometimes helpful.

Answer (score 2):

OK I figured it out. The text file I was viewing had a special character in it. I did "C-x 8 RET 2207" to get the nabla symbol. Emacs renders it as a nabla. If I get rid of that char, scrolling is fine. I won't ask why scrolling is slow w/ the nabla, I am happy to understand the story. And see that emacs can actually scroll quickly on a 2 GHz 64-bit chip.